# QA-C does not give a warning on multiple return statements in one project but does in the other?

Tags: misra, qa-c

At my work place we have just started a new project, and this project also requires MISRA-C checks. And we are using QA-C to perform these.

Our first project is using m2cm message personality, nothing altered.

One of them messages that is turned on is that no multiple return statements per function.

We have just started a new project, different compiler/chip but the same m2cm message personalities and for some reason this warning is no more popping up in the new project. It still is in the other project, using the same `.p_s` file.

This has left us flabbergasted as to why this is happening?

There are no suppression signs anywhere that message 2889 is being suppressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it figured.

The new project was missing the dataflow.pcf file. This has fixed it for us.